# Passing Bitbucket Pipelines Variables to Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, bitbucket, aws-cloudformation

I'm unable to pass Bitbucket repository variables to my AWS Cloudformation template. I need to pass `$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER`. I can echo it to the Bitbucket pipeline, but the variable is never substituted in Cloudformation Parameters.

bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master: 
      - step:
          name: Deploy (Dev)
          deployment: dev
          script:
            - export PARAMETERS=$(cat ./parameters.json)
            - echo "BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER is $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER"
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-cloudformation-deploy:0.18.0
              variables:
                STACK_NAME: 'dev-be-uservice'
                TEMPLATE: 'cloudformation.yml'
                STACK_PARAMETERS: $PARAMETERS
```

parameters.json:

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "BuildTag",
    "ParameterValue": "$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER"
  }
]
```

cloudformation.yml:

```
Parameters:
  BuildTag:
    Description: The Docker Tag
    Type: String
```

In `parameters.json` I've tried `"$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER"`, `"${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}"`, etc.

Cloudformation always shows `BuildTag` as the unsubstituted string (`$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER`) rather than the build number (`2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate the environment variable in the file before the deployment. To do this, you can use `envsubst`:

```json
pipelines:
  branches:
    master: 
      - step:
          name: Deploy (Dev)
          deployment: dev
          script:
            - apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install gettext-base
            - export PARAMETERS=$(envsubst < ./parameters.json)
            - echo "BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER is $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER"
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-cloudformation-deploy:0.18.0
              variables:
                STACK_NAME: 'dev-be-uservice'
                TEMPLATE: 'cloudformation.yml'
                STACK_PARAMETERS: $PARAMETERS
```

e.g.:

```bash
$ cat file
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "BuildTag",
    "ParameterValue": "$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER"
  }
]
$ export BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER=1.0.0
$ export PARAMETERS=$(envsubst < file)
$ echo "$PARAMETERS"
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "BuildTag",
    "ParameterValue": "1.0.0"
  }
]
```